# How to make sure child process finishes copying data into shared memory before join() is called?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, fork, shared-memory

I am using `multiprocessing.Process` to load some images and store them in a shared memory as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745073/why-do-i-get-a-sudden-spike-in-memory-usage-when-using-multiprocessing-process-w). The problem is, sometimes my code crashes due to a huge memory spike at completely random times. I just had an idea of what might be causing this: the process does not have had enough time to copy the contents of the image into the shared memory in RAM by the time `join()`. To test my hypothesis I added `time.sleep(0.015)` after doing `join()` on each of my processes and this has already reduced the number of memory spikes by about 90% or more. However, I'm still not 100% certain whether not getting memory spikes as often is because that little amount of time could help the data to get fully transferred to the shared memory or not.

So I wonder, is there a way to make sure a child process has finished copying data to memory before `.join()` is called? I do not want to use a fixed  number when calling `time.sleep()`. It would be great to to know when the data has been fully transferred to the shared memory and then do `join()`.

Comment: post more context with a shared memory structure

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745073/why-do-i-get-a-sudden-spike-in-memory-usage-when-using-multiprocessing-process-w) help?

Comment: How about using an event, and parent calls `join` once the event is received?

Comment: @heemayl I've never used events. How can I do this? Does the event make sure the contents are fully transferred to the shared memory before I call `join()`? If so, can you provide some code for this?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I can definitely confirm that manually adding `time.sleep(0.015)` after `join()`ing a process has significantly reduced memory spikes; it still happens 10% of the time though. But I'm still not certain whether that is because that little amount of time could help the data to get fully transferred to the shared memory or not.

Comment: @Amir, did you check how's that adjusted time delay depends on different amount of data ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I did a simple test for that and it seems that the higher the amount of data, the more likely I will run into the memory spike issue.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I wonder, should I manually lock an array when writing into it? I just saw some posts that seem to suggest people should start filling the `mp.Array` object using `with arr.get_lock()` statement. Although I'm never writing into the same array using multiple processes, but I'm afraid memory is not allocated to my jobs in the logical way that we think about it. So it's possible that sometimes two jobs on our server have overlapping physical memory addresses allocated to them?

Comment: I'm unsure how a sleep helps, `join`ing a process just waits (i.e. sleeps) until the target exits